# Form set to be used for data entry attempting to create duplicate records causing error

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2013

I have a form that is set to be used for data entry that is not working. When the form opens it is blank however when anything is entered in any field the primary key field (visible but not editable on the form) sets itself to a value that is already in use. The rest of the fields on the main form remain blank however I have subforms that fill with values corresponding to the primary key. The source of the form is a single table that is linked to the database from the backend. The table has no missing records. The exact error I get when I try to then close the form is:

*"The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again."*

The same error is occurring on another form that is then used only for updating records. The error appears anytime anything is entered into a field on a subform.

Any ideas are appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, Access inserts automatically new value to autonumber field, and this value already exists. If so, run compact & repair, it will set autonumber next value to max in field + 1

Access generates new value for autonumber fields using internal counter, not maximum value. This internal counter can be set by inserting any value to autonumber field using, for instance, `INSERT` SQL statement, also it can be done in some cases during editing data in forms with linked subforms. Internal counter resets to last inserted value + 1. After compact & repair counter resets to actual maximum value +1.